# Summernotejs: Every word's first letter is autocaptialized

Tags: javascript, summernote

I am using summernote text editor for my web application. The problem I am facing is that when I type anything and hit spacebar the first letter of every word is auto capitalized. I can't figure out how to disable this behavior. Not able to find anything related to this in the documentation.

[image]

Summernotejs configuration code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Start writting here....',
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],

                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', []],
                ['view', []],
                ['Misc', ['undo', 'redo']]
            ],

            spellCheck: false,
            tooltip: false,
            height: 300,

        });
    })
```

Comment: I think what are the settings of your operating system. Is you use mac os, check this settings: https://osxdaily.com/2016/11/22/capitalize-words-automatically-period-double-space-mac/

Comment: @DenisStukalov I use Ubuntu & same happening on the windows machine.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi Have you ever found a solution for this? I have the same issue

Comment: @Matrix I had to switch to CKEditor.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi thanks for the reply. I actually figured what was the problem in my case, parent div had a "text-capitalize" bootstrap class, which capitalizes each letter, overwriting this style for summernote fixed my issue.